# Cannot edit users in Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, user, gack

I am encountering an issue in my sandbox in which any time I make an edit to a user account, I receive the following error message:

---

**Unable to Finish Processing Request**

An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact support@salesforce.com. Please indicate the URL of the page you were requesting as well as any other related information. We apologize for the inconvenience.

Thank you again for your patience and assistance. And thanks for using salesforce.com!

Error ID: 110505560-29005 (1115406996)

---

I haven't encountered any issues making changes to the User object in general - only making any change to user records. The error message is always the same.

I've looked around in stack exchange, google searches, and the trailblazer community but haven't been able to find anyone encountering the same issue.

Does anyone know why this might be happening, and how to resolve it? The issue only occurs in my sandbox - changes in production have no such issue.

Comment: You'll need to open a case with Salesforce support.  In Salesforce, click your name > Help & Training at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I did log a support case with Salesforce and they identified the problem right away. The problem stemmed from a custom field we have on our user object that references an image link. Something about the sandbox broke that link, and caused the error message to occur any time a change to the user record was made. Removing the link allowed editing again.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it happens sometimes when processing org copy.
You couldn't operate any DML on the object.

In some situtations, a '**Truncate**' may take effects on Custom Object. 
But it's better to log a case to Salesforce Support.
Or Refresh the Sandbox immediately.